# is there any helper modules for i18n using django?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

i want to translate my webpage. but using i18n module in django, it looks like it is impossible.

on django internationlization tutorial they say to edit all po files.

the po files

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2013-05-27 10:16+0530\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1)\n"

#: registration/admin.py:23
msgid "Activate users"
msgstr ""

#: registration/admin.py:43
msgid "Re-send activation emails"
msgstr ""

#: registration/forms.py:34
msgid "Username"
msgstr "uuuuuuuuuuuu"
```

edit to languages which i don't know is very very hard. so i would like to know any apps that will automatically translate..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am not aware of any "auto-translate" django apps for this. It would be an interesting though...

I know of a nifty Django App called - [django-mothertongue](http://pythonhosted.org/django-mothertongue/). This app makes it very easy to detect and add support for a new language. This should be perfect for dealing with static text being shown in different languages. For example you have some static text X and what to show this in 20 different languages. Use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) to manually translate X to these 20 languages and store it.

But the problem with this is that it does not do auto-translate.

Auto language translate is a complex feature involving deep language understanding and NLP techniques  and for a django app to do it is impractical. What I would suggest you do it to take the help of [Google Translate Developers API](https://developers.google.com/translate/) and plug it in to the either `django-mothertongue` or directly into `django-i18`. So with Google Translate you could theoretically do on the fly language detection and language translate from one language to another. If you are taking this approach beware that Google Translate is still leaning model and I have seen it goof up royally in more cases than one.